# IIS 8.5: Failed Request Tracing missing from IIS Manager

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8, tracing

In Windows Server 2012 R2, I've installed the IIS "Tracing" module. However when I start IIS Manager, I don't see the Failed Request Tracing option anywhere, in any pane or properties window of any object.

What do I need to do to convince IIS that I really do want to use Request Tracing??

Answer (score 13):

See also: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/tracefailedrequestslogging

> - On the taskbar, click Start, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Server Manager.
> - In the Server Manager hierarchy pane, expand Roles, and then click Web Server (IIS).
> - In the Web Server (IIS) pane, scroll to the Role Services section, and then click Add Role Services.
> - On the Select Role Services page of the Add Role Services Wizard, select Tracing, and then click Next.

Comment: To add a little extra information: Tracing is under Web Server / Health and Diagnostics

Answer (score 0):

The applet to create FRT rules is in inetmgr.msc. Open the msc as admin, expand your default website, and select your site/applicaiton. an icon for Failed Request Tracking should appear in the features tab.

if it does not, have you rebooted since installing the module? can you confirm `FailedRequestsTracingModule` displays in inetmgr -> modules? are you sure its selected in Appwiz.cpl -> Add Remove windows Features?